# unset variable done before it should unset

Tags: php

I have this peace of code of which I don't understand why it's not working as I expect.

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
  $_SESSION['reg'] = "done";
  header("Location: " . SELF, true, 302);
}

if((isset($_SESSION['reg']) AND ($_SESSION['reg'] == "done"))) {
  unset($_SESSION['reg']);
  echo "Done";
}else{
  echo "Not done";
}
?>
```

After `POST` it redirects and echo's `Not done` but I would expect it would echo's `Done`. If I remove the line with unset, it works fine and echo's `Done`.

This isn't the behavior I would expect. What mistake am I making?

Comment: Is `session_start();` indeed loaded?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yes it is. Didn't show it in the code

Comment: Try Steve's answer. Pretty sure that should fix it.

Comment: See also what `Deadman` has. Missing bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A header redirect does not stop execution of the script, so the unset is carried out immediately.

To fix `exit` after the redirect

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
  $_SESSION['reg'] = "done";
  header("Location: " . SELF, true, 302);
  exit();//<-- add this
}

if((isset($_SESSION['reg']) AND ($_SESSION['reg'] == "done"))) {
  unset($_SESSION['reg');
  echo "Done";
}else{
  echo "Not done";
}

?>
```

Comment: aaargggg, now I also understand why this was working perfectly on other pages where I indeed put in the `exit`. Just forgot it for this page! Many thanks! BTW, just using `exit` is enough though? Or is it better to do `exit()`.

Comment: *"`exit();//<-- add this`"* - Actually, using just `exit;` instead of `exit();` is apparently better. There was a similar question a day or so ago where the person's answer mentioned something to the effect of, `exit()` with brackets has to work a bit harder. Just a sidenote.

Comment: `exit; exit(); die; die();` all function the same, although there is perhaps a tiny overhead to using function notation (brackets). I use brackets because i sometimes need to send an error message. When i don't, i feel its still better to be consistent, but that's a matter of opinion. Anyway, glad i could help you

Comment: For sure Steve. I guess it's kind of a "poh-tay-toe, poh-tah-toe" type of thing lol - either way works.

Answer (score 0):

write this `unset($_SESSION['reg']);` instead of this `unset($_SESSION['reg');`

Comment: *"write this `unset($_SESSION['reg']);` instead of this `unset($_SESSION['reg');`"* - Errr..... *huh?*

Comment: closing square bracket is missing.

Comment: LOL! sorry, I didn't see that missing bracket. My bad.

Comment: That was a type! Didn't exist in the real code! Fixed my question.